# Azure Website 404 (Not Found) on PHP Resources

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, azure

I'm new to all things coding and have tried to use Azure to host a web app.  The app is JavaScript using PHP to process MYSQL data.  Everything works locally as expected.  But when I try to access the app where it's hosted, I see 404 (Not Found) errors on all of my calls to .php files.

I'm using jQuery's `getJSON` to get data:

```
$.getJSON('bin/myFile.php', function(data) {
  // Process data
})
```

Then in the browser console I see:

```
GET https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/bin/myFile.php 404 (Not Found)
```

But, if I move that file to the root directory and drop the `bin/` from my call, it works perfectly.  All other calls to files in folders work fine (images, scripts, styles), only the php files in the bin folder return this error.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Try renaming your `bin` folder. That is normally where binary files are placed in a windows web app environment, so it's possible the Azure server is configured to not serve any files from that location

Comment: Bless you, that worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from comments:

Try renaming your bin folder. That is normally where binary files are placed in a windows web app environment, so it's possible the Azure server is configured to not serve any files from that location –
Rory McCrossan
Sep 26 '17 at 16:22